# How can I implement the equivalent of a split view container in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm looking to port a WinForms app to WPF. I have a classic split view container in the form which I need to replicate in WPF. Not a hamburger menu or the like, but a full on split view with a slider the user can use to resize horizontally or vertically as needed.

I can't imagine I'm the first one to need this but for the life of me, I can't find a solution. I guess I just don't know the correct keywords to use in searching for this. Any advice is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WinForms, but have a look at the GridSplitter.

Comment: That was the magic sauce I was looking for. I'd tried that before, but it didn't do anything. However, I dug a little deeper per your suggestion and it's exactly what I needed. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

As gdir's comment says, try the GridSplitter.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

It needs to sit in it's own cell of the grid, and you can change between Rows and Columns with the `ResizeDirection` property.